# Use Powershell and Regex to extract block of lines from a text file

Tags: regex, powershell, text-parsing

I'm developing Powershell scripts and .Net Regex to find pattern matching in the network device configuration using powershell and regex. I am having problem trying to extract a block of strings from the config file and also having problem to write regex statement to match the carriage return and the new line.  Below is my example.  I have a config file with information below that I want to extract

```
vlan no  description  ports
999      unused       Gi1/2,Gi1/3, Gi1/4, Gi1/5, Gi1/6, Gi/7, Gi/8, Gi1/9
                      Gi1/0, Gi1/11, Gi1/12, Gi1/13, Gi1/14, Gi1/15, Gi1/16
                      Gi1/17, Gi1/18
```

Here is my code

```
$File = Get-content C:\config.txt

$Regex = "(?sm)(^999.*(\r\n\s+.*)"
$unused_ports = Select-String -path $File -Pattern $Regex 
Write-host $Unused_ports
```

it only displays the first line

```
999      unused       Gi1/2,Gi1/3, Gi1/4, Gi1/5, Gi1/6, Gi/7, Gi/8, Gi1/9
```

I also tried the following $Regex

```
$Regex = '(?m)(^999.*\s+Gi1/10.*)
$Regex = '(?m)(^999.*\r\n\s+Gi1/10.*)
```

But none of the regex statements I used extracted all the ports (3 lines)

I also used `get-content c:\config.txt -raw` but this would display everything thing in the config file.

Really appreciate if someone can help to extract all three lines with port numbers and how to use carriage return and new line to match the new line.

Comment: What do you want to obtain? Just the three lines from the above text? Use `get-content c:\config.txt -raw` approach and then try a simple `(?m)^999.*(?:\r?\n.*){2}`.

Comment: You have a greedy quantifier (`.*`), so yeah, it's going to get *everything* when you use that. You probably want to change it to `.*?` for better results. And yeah, you need to use `-raw`. It would be very helpful to see more of the file.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried the -raw and it shows the entire config which has lots of other information that I don't need.  Can you explain what the (?:\r?\n.*){2} does?  I don't have the config file now but will try to upload it tomorrow

Comment: @Justin: `(?:..)` is a non-capturing group (used in case there's no need to capture what's inside _separately_); `\r?\n` matches both Windows- and Unix-style newlines (CRLF and LF). `(?:\r?\n.*){2}` therefore matches the next 2 lines _unconditionally_ (note how the omission of option `s` makes `.` _not_ match `\n`), which works well with your specific sample input - however, it falls short if your real input has blocks  with varying numbers of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question<sup>[1]</sup>
: You must use `Get-Content -Raw` to read the file contents into a *single* string so your regex can match *across lines*:

```
if ((Get-Content -Raw C:\Config.txt) -match '(?ms)^999.*?(?=\r?\n\S|\Z)') { 
  $Matches[0]  # automatic variable $Matches reflects what was captured
}
```

The regex needed some tweaking, too, including the use of *non-greedy* quantifier `.*?`, as suggested by [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician):

- `(?ms)` sets regex options `m` (treats `^` and `$` as *line* anchors) and `s` (makes `.` match `\n` (newlines) too`.
- `^999.*?` matches any line starting with `999` and any subsequent characters non-greedily.
- `(?=\r?\n\S|\Z)` is a positive *look-ahead assertion* (`(?=...)`) that matches either a newline (`\r?\n`) followed by a non-whitespace character (`\S`) - assumed to be the start of the *next* block - or (`|`) the very end of the input (`\Z`) - in effect, this matches either the end of the file or the start of the next block , but without including it in in the match recorded in `$Matches`.

---

<sup>[1] Wiktor also suggests regex `(?m)^999.*(?:\r?\n.*){2}`, which works well with the sample input, but is limited to blocks that have exactly 3 lines - by contrast, the solution presented here finds blocks of any length, as long as the non-initial block lines all have leading whitespace.</sup>