# regex can't be first element for pipeline - how get match

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a regular expression that is run at the windows 10 command line, and get the error:

```
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
```

I'm not sure how to put this together with the match part in the first element.

This is the document content (with important parts shown...there are multiple Manufacturer and S/N's but I just need the specific one):

e:\temp\details.txt:

```
...
  Manufacturer: SGSS
  S/N: A791D734804

...
```

I successfully get the above two lines of code from the document with this powershell, but I'm having trouble extracting the serial number after the semicolon.

This works to extract the Manufacturer and S/N lines (Context part gets line after pattern match too):

```
powershell "Get-Content e:\temp\details.txt | select-String -Pattern SGSS -Context 0,1"
```

However, I'm trying to return just the serial number (), and get the error above.  This is where I get the error with the match/command:

```
powershell "Get-Content -Raw e:\temp\details.txt | select-String -Pattern SGSS -Context 0,1 | $_ -match '(?ms)(N:\s)(([a-zA-Z0-9])+)'"
```

I tested that the regular expression works in a regex tester:

```
(N:\s)(([a-zA-Z0-9])+)
```

I used this [example for the match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141781/use-powershell-and-regex-to-extract-block-of-lines-from-a-text-file) , but I can't put it first in the expression (like the example) because of the other things I'm doing.  What do you recommend?

**Update:**
Example document contents:

```
A00232473244B

USB xController
RootHub
Port[6] USB Reader
Manufacturer: Gen 
S/N: 0A0000002071



Intel(R) 8 Series/1234 Series 
RootHub
Port[1]Standard-USB-Hub


USB x Controller
RootHub
Port[1] abc Printer
Manufacturer: guess
S/N: A2622431

Port[2] SG
Manufacturer: SGSS
S/N: A791B634801
```

**Update2:**

I tried this regex in a regex tester and it's still only finding the first S/N line but not following ones or just the SGSS one I care about:

```
S\/N:\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\n\r\S\s]*
```

**Update3:**
Some things I tried that are returning nothing:

```
powershell -command Get-Content e:\temp\details.txt -Raw ^| Where{$_ -match '(?ms)SGSS[\r\n\s]*S\/N: (\S+)\b'} ^| ForEach-Object { $Matches[1]}

powershell -command Get-Content e:\temp\details.txt -Raw ^| Where{$_ -match '(?ms)SGSS[\r\n\s]*S\/N: (\S+)\b'} ^| ForEach-Object { echo $Matches[1]}

powershell -command Get-Content e:\temp\details.txt -Raw ^| Where{$_ -match '(?ms)SGSS[\n\r]S\/N:\s([\w]*)'} ^| ForEach-Object { echo $Matches[1]}

powershell -command Get-Content e:\temp\details.txt -Raw ^| select-string -Pattern 'SGSS[\n\r]S\/N:\s([\w]*)' ^| ForEach-Object { echo $Matches[1]}

powershell -command Get-Content e:\temp\devices.txt -Raw ^| Where{$_ -match '(?ms)SGSS[\r\n\s]*S/N: (\S+)\b'} ^| ForEach-Object { $Matches[1]}
```

**Update4:**

I tried this and it's still returning nothing, with no errors as well. It's possible the issue is newlines/spaces.  I'm not sure.

powershell -Command Get-Content 'e:\temp\details.txt' ^| Foreach-Object {  if($_ -match 'SGSS') {$Found=1};  if(($_ -match 'S/N:\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\n\r\S\s]*') -and ($Found -eq 1)) {$_ -replace '^.*N:\s' }}

**Update5:**

I'm trying testing it at the command line of our device, which is windows 10, and tried putting it in a ps1 file to run. I'm getting errors or nothing with this (ran at the command line with c:\temp>powershell ./SG_SN.ps1):

```
powershell "Get-Content e:\temp\details.txt -Raw | select-String -Pattern 'SGSS[\n\r]S\/N:\s([\w]*)'  | ForEach-Object {echo $Matches[1]}"
```

result: Nothing returned, no error

```
powershell "Get-Content e:\temp\usbconnecteddevices.txt -Raw ^| select-String -Pattern 'SAWGRASS[\n\r]S\/N:\s([\w]*)'  ^| ForEach-Object {echo $Matches[1]}"
```

result: error:

```
Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '^'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content e:\temp\details.txt -Raw ^| select-String -Pa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Note, I don't want to test it in powershell ISE or at the PS prompt because we can't run it that way ultimately.

**Update6:**
This seems to be working in PowershellISE. I'll test it in the command line next. It's based on something from my notes for the last year or more.

```
Get-Content 'e:\temp\details.txt' | select-String -Pattern SGSS -Context 0,1 |
ForEach-Object -Process { $result = $_ -split ':'; echo 'here';$result[-1]}
```

Comment: "we can't run it that way ultimately"... You are running it that way ultimately.  You are calling a PowerShell.exe execution with a  command parameter (passing a script block into PowerShell), just *started* from a cmd.exe prompt.  Everything after your starting "powershell" (quoted and with or without the -command ) is executed in PowerShell not cmd.exe.  Unquoted however the content after -command is still interpreted by cmd.exe, so without quotes you need to have escape characters (like ^) to be able to pass the entire command string to PowerShell.

Comment: UPDATE #5.  Select-String does not automatically do a Match and populate the $Matches automatic variable.  You need to explicitly execute a -match on your regex pattern.

Comment: The "echo" you are using is actually an PowerShell alias for the PS cmdlet "Write-Output", so you may as well include that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Where-Object` and the automatic `$Matches` variable in a `ForEach-Object` scriptblock to get what you want:

```
powershell -command Get-Content e:\temp\details.txt -raw ^| Where{$_ -match '(?ms)SGSS[\r\n\s]*S/N: (\S+)\b'} ^| ForEach-Object {$Matches[1]}
```

Updated to escape the pipes and fix quoting issue.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon do you mean Where{\$_ -match 'N: ...

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - I'm trying the above without escaping, and (given my multiple manufacturers and S/N:'s it's not returning any results. Any ideas? Maybe it's missing spaces or newlines?

Comment: My test regular expression with N: in my description assumes we are pulling my two lines out with select-string -pattern -context. Maybe that's what the problem is with the answer?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I tried replacing your @' with double quotes but it's has error Unexpected token 'Manufacturer:' in expression or statement. powershell "'$captureNext = $false; switch -Regex -File e:\temp\details.txt {  'Manufacturer: \bSGSS\b' { $captureNext = $true; continue }  { $captureNext } {$_ -replace '\x*S/N:\s*'; break }}'"

Comment: TheMadTechnician, I added an Update showing example document contents.  You can see with that, using the regex you're using, it's finding the first S/N: and quits.  The SGSS one is farther down in the document.

Comment: ok, I had to fix some escaping for cmd parsing, and change how it's quoted, but that worked for me.

Comment: TheMadTechnician, did you add the carrot ^ on purpose? I've never seen that.  I'm trying what you have and have error- 'ForEach-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Michele, the caret (`^`) is `cmd.exe`'s escape character, and required here, because, in the absence of enclosing `"...."`, `cmd.exe` would otherwise interpret the `|` chars. as _its_ pipeline operator.

Comment: @mklement0 - and TheMadTechnician, I tried a few versions and see why -command and carrots are needed now. It's still not finding the SGSS serial number.  See things tried in update3.

Comment: I saved your example to a .txt file, launched cmd.exe, ran the first command in your Update3 section (replacing the path for mine), and it returned the info you want. Something isn't adding up here.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks for the check.  I will try directly at cmd.exe tomorrow and see if I get good results. I appreciate it. I'm going through our interface to the devices, which usually takes normal one-line shell commands. It's possible it's removing weird characters. I've seen it remove +. But there's no error.

Comment: sounds like it's something specific with your interface. You may have other escapes that need to be implemented similarly to how I used the `^` to escape the pipes.

Comment: I tried logging into a device and pasting the powershell command at the windows command prompt and it returns nothing. I typed the file out and it does exist. Maybe it's the -command formatting?

Comment: Explained a bit more in an edit to the answer below. Try removing both carets(^) and encapsulating everything after -command in double quotes.   powershell -command "full command string without carets". This should pass entire command string to powershell, but the carets would cause problems for powershell execution.  They are only needed for cmd.exe shell execution.

Comment: "I typed the file out and it does exist"... Is this file on a remote device or your local one? Are launching your Windows 10 cmd.exe, connecting (Telnet,SSH, etc) to another device, then executing your PowerShell call? If so, depending on the device you are connecting to, perhaps it does not have PowerShell.exe? If some off your testing returned results, was it local testing or remote?

Comment: All of your recent updates are completely missing `-command`

Comment: My Update6 is running fine without -command or carrots. It returns the SN.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try setting a flag variable and then act on next match of your pattern. This was tested against a test file of your details.txt example above.
It correctly selected your SGSS S/N#. I did alter it slightly so that on successful match of "SGSS", it just removed the "S/N: " text.

Here is the multi-line formatting. If you compose it single-line you will need the semi-colon in the ForEach-Object block, I believe.

```
powershell -Command Get-Content 'e:\temp\details.txt' | 
    Foreach-Object {
        if($_ -match 'SGSS') { $Found = 1 };
        if(($_ -match 'S\/N:\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\n\r\S\s]*') -and ($Found -eq 1)) { $_ -replace '^.*N:\s' }
    }
```

And Single-Liner:

```
powershell -Command Get-Content 'e:\temp\details.txt' ^| Foreach-Object { if($_ -match 'SGSS') { $Found = 1 }; if(($_ -match 'S\/N:\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\n\r\S\s]*') -and ($Found -eq 1)) { $_ -replace '^.*N:\s' } }
```

**EDIT:** It seems you had the most luck with your entire PowerShell command encapsulated in double quotes. It seems more an issue of getting your entire command string passed to powershell versus not having the correct powershell commands to retrieve your data. Perhaps the commands just above would run on your particular device interface if they were encapsulated like below.

```
powershell "Get-Content 'e:\temp\details.txt' | Foreach-Object { if($_ -match 'SGSS') { $Found = 1 }; if(($_ -match 'S\/N:\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\n\r\S\s]*') -and ($Found -eq 1)) { $_ -replace '^.*N:\s' } }"
```

This ran successfully on cmd.exe and retrieved the S/N#, but I cannot say if it will run on your device interface.

Also, using your original command with the addition of "ForEach-Object" and an expression of the Match results ($Matches[2]), I received same results. I believe the error you originally received was a result of expressing $_ outside of a Foreach-Object block.

```
powershell "Get-Content e:\temp\details.txt | select-String -Pattern SGSS -Context 0,1 | ForEach-Object { $_ -match '(?ms)(N:\s)(([a-zA-Z0-9])+)'; $Matches[2] }"
```

Results

```
True
A791B634801
```

The "True" output can be removed by adjusting here... { $_ -match 'regex' | Out-Null; $Matches[2] }

As far as your original error, I believe you were piping to a variable ( $_ ), an expression assignment operation, as the below example shows.

```
"THIS IS A TEST STRING PIPED TO A VARIABLE" | $TEST

    At line:1 char:49
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
    
$TEST = "THIS IS A TEST STRING PIPED TO A VARIABLE" | ForEach-Object { $_ }

No Error
```

Comment: Ah... In cmd.exe I needed the (^) as well before the  pipe to ForEach-Object

Comment: I tried this and it's returning nothing.  Any ideas? Could it be spacing/newlines? powershell -Command Get-Content 'e:\temp\details.txt' ^| Foreach-Object {  if($_ -match 'SGSS') {$Found=1};  if(($_ -match 'S\/N:\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\n\r\S\s]*') -and ($Found -eq 1)) {$_ -replace '^.*N:\s' }}

Comment: It worked for me directly at cmd.exe prompt and pointed at a test file with your contents.  I'm thinking it's a result of, as mentioned above, you are using a device interface similar to cmd.exe, but it may not operate the same exactly.

Comment: My Update6 is running and it returns the SN.  Thank you for your help! I'm not sure why your solution isn't working for me.  Thanks again!